# Object doesn't support this property or method - expected behaviour but how do I hide the message?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

My site is working fine but im getting an annoying error icon in bottom left of the IE8 browser. The error message is 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. The reason this is happening is that the code below is in a javascript file that loads on every page. However the plugin that 'cycle' uses is only loaded on the page where its needed, creating this error on ever other page.

```
$('#mydiv').cycle({
    fx:     'fade'
});
```

This doesn't break anything in my site but it looks unprofessional to have this error icon. Other than putting the js above only on the page that has the plugin, is there another solution to this? Thanks

Comment: excuse me sir, but it looks more unprofessional that this code is executed at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but is there a practice downside to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($().cycle) {
    // code that uses .cycle()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if($.fn.cycle)
{
    $('#mydiv').cycle({
        fx:     'fade'
    });

}
```

This code will check if the cycle plugin is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception before it reaches the browser:

```
try {
  <your code here>
} catch (exception) {
  // ignore exception
}
```